# Python replace method with a decorator

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, decorator

I have a Python dictionary
basket={fruit:'apple',vegetable:'kale'}

and a helper function , that wherever it sees the words fruits and vegetables in the Execution query , it will replace it with apple and kale respectively.

Helper function :

```
      def replaceQuery(self,query,**basket):


            for key , value in basket.items():

                if key in query:
                    query=query.replace(key,value)

            return query
```

Next , I am using the query returned from this method and passing on to the execution method

```
      query =replaceQuery(query,basket)
      
      executeQuery(Client, query)
```

The execution Method is as below:

```
     def executeQuery(Client,query):

        result=Client.query(query)
```

I have been learning decorators and was wondering if i can add a decorator on the executeQuery()
method , so that every time it gets called , it will first replace teh Query string to replace all the fruits and vegetables values .Something similar to this

```
@replaceQuery
def executeQuery(Client,query)
   ......
   ......
```

Any help or suggestions with adding a decorator to this process will be helpful

Comment: Is query always a dict type?

Comment: No the dict is the basket which has the mapping .The query is a string .Eg: select * from table where column1=fruit.

Comment: You're not passing any replacements to `replaceQuery()`. If you intend to use the global variable `basket`, it shouldn't be a function parameter.

Comment: Otherwise, it should be `query = replaceQuery(query, **basket)`

Comment: When you do this replacement, it won't put `kale` in quotes in the query.

Comment: correct , My bad .I will update the question

Comment: It seems like you're trying to implement placeholders in the query. That's already implemented in `cursor.execute()`

Comment: i am using a Big Query Client , And was curious if the same capability can be done by leveraging decorators

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve the same functionality using decorator,
as shown in example below

```
def replaceQuery(decorated):
    @wraps(decorated)
    def replace(Client, query, basket):
        # code to run before the decorated func
        for key , value in basket.items():
            if key in query:
                query=query.replace(key,value)

        # running the decorated func
        return decorated(Client, query, basket)
    return replace

@replaceQuery
def executeQuery(Client, query, basket):
    ......
    ......
```

In Python functions are like any other object,
by adding @replaceQuery decorator to executeQuery function, you actually call replaceQuery with executeQuery replaceQuery(executeQuery) so decorated object refers to executeQuery func.
When running executeQuery() replace() will be invoked, so you can add the functionality you want to get executed before running the decorated function (executeQuery) in replace func, and after that to call executeQuery.